# Can't run any scripts, Traceback, FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pandas, directory

Earlier this week I put together my first ever working python script. I am trying to create another one in a different directory, but when I try to run any script at all (using Notepad++) I get an error that shows Python seems to be trying to access the old directory and not finding it, even though I haven't told it to look in the old directory. Now the original script doesn't work either. This is what the error message looks like, no matter what I try to run:

```
python "C:\Users\me\Documents\oldDirectory\oldScript.py"
Process started (PID=12884) >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\Documents\oldDirectory\oldScript.py", line 13, in <module>
    month = pd.read_csv(sheet)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 610, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 462, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1050, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1867, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1362, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 642, in get_handle
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\me\Documents\oldDirectory\Table.csv'
<<< Process finished (PID=12884). (Exit code 1)
```

As you might guess from the error message, my original script used pd.read_csv() and accessed Table.csv. No matter what I try to run, I get this error. What's going on?

Comment: This is not reproducible for anyone, could be many reasons why this is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can check again the path of you file to read. If it's not wrong, try without the '.csv' at the end of the file path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I was using Notepad++ and not the code I was running. To run a script in that environment you press F6 and a dialog pops up asking what you want to execute. This does NOT default to whichever .py you have open at the moment, so when it hit ctrl+F6 to skip the dialog, it kept trying to run my old script.